# Strange Video Display Issue w/SimpleModal in Firefox

Tags: jquery, simplemodal, firefox4

I have a very strange issue that ONLY happens in FireFox 4 (works fine in IE and FF3.6). When a user clicks a video link, it opens up a jquery/simplemodal box. The audio portion of the file begins just fine - however, the video portion does not display until the user makes some form of mouse movement/click (or hits the Alt Key). Can anyone explain what may cause this.

TIA for any help

Answer (score 1):

I just found the answer - It is actually a KNOWN BUG w/FF4

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=651999

Comment: Glad to hear it's not SimpleModal! This one had me stumped ;)